# Visual Studio Code Comments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can i select multiple lines in my python code and comment them with just one click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvPHq.png)

Comment: "ctrl+/" is how you comment multiple lines

Comment: highlight the lines you wish to comment and press `ctrl+/`

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio/VSCode hold `shift` and drag to select the lines and then press `ctrl+k+c` to comment and `ctrl+k+u` to uncomment

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + /` (the slash key) to comment and uncomment lines of Python code on Windows. `Command + /` to comment and uncomment multiple lines of Python code on Mac.

[Windows VSCode shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

[macOS keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + /`  or  `ctrl + ?` comments out selected lines of code in Visual Studio Code. The same command can be used to uncomment selected code.